# Azure Service Fabric Stateless Web API + API Management + B2C Auth tutorial

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I am looking for a end to end tutorial for Service Fabric Stateless Asp.ent Web api which Integrates with Azure Api Management. I want to add Azure AD B2C Auth for the Web ApI through API Management. Any tutorial/Guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already read this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management

I used the article today, where all routes for a specific APIM product require a valid JWT from AD B2C.

After that its up to you to add Authorization based logic in your ASP.NET classes/controllers to handle what the user is allowed to do based on that user.

Comment: Did you use Service Fabric Service/Web Api? How did you integrate SF with API management

Comment: No I didnt use SF for APIM, but its documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-api-management